# Magento popup button location

Tags: php, ajax, magento, magento-1.7

I am looking to track down the file (and it's location) that generates the 2 buttons on Magento. When I hit "add to basket button" on any product on the homepage a pop-up with 2 buttons appears. I am unable to translate the buttons (not images). I did tried to locate it for a couple of days, but no success. Inspect element/view source/including developer extensions doesnt help me at all. Website: haratoys.ro

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you can do:

- [**grep**](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/) - always useful. Look through templates **AND** `app/code/local`, **AND** `app/code/community`. Or use an IDE that can search through all the files.
- **Check the admin panel**. Some extensions may use widgets or insert blocks in textareas. Normally, when adding buttons programmatically, there  will be an option to edit them
- When all fails, search the **database directly**. First, look in `core_config_data`, then try searching through the custom tables, and if all else fails, look through the whole database (phpmyadmin has such functionality).

If none of these help, someone screwed up really bad. Check for symlinks or encoded information, maybe even remotely loaded content, javascript generated content (although this should be found with `grep`).

Also, try searching for identifiers that are not general. Looking for the "Add to cart" text may not find what you need, but searching for the button id will get you some useful information. Also check case sensitivity.

Comment: Salut, Vlad. :) Unfortunately I did manage to try 1st and 2nd suggestions, but with no luck. The grep and database searching is way out of my league and ive just hit the maximum of my technical skills. :)

Comment: Salut! Just use an IDE that can search through files, and the search function in phpmyadmin and they should do the job

Answer (score 0):

It's probably custom to your theme, but it may be located in

`app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml`

This is where I was able to change the content of the links, so it's possible that they are in the same location.

What Vlad said, however, is the best way to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Thx, Jacob, but I did look into this file earlier.

Yes, its custom to my theme. I am waiting for a comment from the developer, since 3 weeks.

I am pretty sure that is not remotely loaded content because the theme was tested locally, without internet connection.